# When will expo-image-picker return an HEIC file on IOS?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an IOS react native app that uses expo-image-picker to get images from the Image Library and  Camera. When testing the app through Expo Go on an iPhone SE, the uri in `ImagePicker.ImageInfo` always gives a jpg file.

This behavior persists even when I upload an HEIC file to my phone, and use that file with the image picker. I also have High Efficiency setting enabled in the format section of the camera settings.

While this is my desired behavior, I don't want to rely on a misunderstanding of the library. Nowhere in the [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/) are HEIC files mentioned, except for one example that indicates it is possible for the library to retrieve HEIC files.

Is it possible to get HEIC files, if so how?